# Routing module stop working: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'xxxModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-router, angular-module

I have a weird issue with routing module. The routing module used to work. However, after I added another project routing module in a different folder with different module name, I got error on this project when trying to navigate to step 1.

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'Step1Module' in './+step1/step1.module'.

step1.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AbcComponent } from './abc.component';
import { StepGuardService } from './shared/step-guard/step-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AbcComponent, children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'step1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'step1',
        loadChildren: './+step1/step1.module#Step1Module',
        data: {
          preload: true,
          stepNumberOnNavigator: 1
        },
        canActivate: [StepGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: 'step2',
        loadChildren: './+step2/step2.module#Step2Module',
        data: {
          preload: true,
          stepNumberOnNavigator: 2
        },
        canActivate: [StepGuardService]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AbcRoutingModule { }
```

To fix this, I have to re-type the module name "Step1Module" with the exactly same letters (basically copy and paste) on the line of

```
loadChildren: './+step1/step1.module#Step1Module',
```

and save the file. Then the error will be gone and the project will be running. I don't understand what's going on here. Since nothing actually changed, I can't push anything to git to fix the issue on the server side too.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Updates: routing module for step1 and step2

step1-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { Step1Component } from './step1.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Step1Component,
    data: {
      bannerTitle: 'xxx',
      pageTitle: 'xxx'
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Step1RoutingModule { }
```

step2-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { Step2Component } from './step2.component';
import { Step2aComponent } from '../+step2/step2a/step2a.component';
import { QuestionnaireDetailComponent } from './questionnaire-detail/questionnaire-detail.component';
import { EligibilityDeclineComponent } from './eligibility-decline/eligibility-decline.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Step2aComponent,
    data: {
      bannerTitle: 'xxx',
      pageTitle: 'xxx'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'eligibility',
    component: Step2Component,
    data: {
      bannerTitle: 'xxx',
      pageTitle: 'xxx'
    }
  },
...
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Step2RoutingModule { }
```

Comment: can we have a look at your routes definition for the module Step2Module ? Are you sure you used a forChild for this one and not a forRoot ?

Comment: @WilliamKLEIN I added the two routes definitions in my post just now. Yes, I'm sure I use for Child. Thanks!

Comment: @JulieC.your problem has been solved your question scenario using my answer. so kindly mark as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly apply **full path** to your module. Change this line to following in **step1.module** file:

```
 children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: 'app/components/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    }
   ]
```

these is only sample data please replace your data.
let try this once and please let me know.

Note :- The path start **app/path/to/module/** like this full path.

For your doubt visit these website and note that **loadChildren** line

https://scotch.io/tutorials/lazy-loading-in-angular-v2

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

I hope this solve your problem.

Thanks,

Karnan Muthu.

Comment: Thanks, the full path works. Unfortunate, after team discussion, we decided not to go for that direction since we prefer routing module to have relative path to lazy loaded modules. We solved this issue by renaming the new added project routing module. It looks like an bug in Angular CLI, which can not recognize the proper module when there are two modules having the same name, even they are in totally different folders.

Comment: If it is work your asked question scenario so please mark as answer and upvote.